# Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apt

I'm trying to instal Krita on Linux Ubuntu 16.4 
by following this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install krita
```

I'm getting this when I try second command (for update):

```
    Err:1 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
Err:2 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  xenial-backports InRelease                 
  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.3:8080:
Err:3  http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  xenial-updates InRelease                  
  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.3:8080:
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu  xenial InRelease                             
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
Err:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                             
 Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
Err:7  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                        
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done             
W: Failed to fetch  http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease   Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch  http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.3:8080:
W: Failed to fetch   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
W: Failed to http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 172.16.0.3:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease   Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

-I'm not using proxy 
-The first command also doesn't work:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

-The third command too, but I won't type anything about third, because I think the main problem is:

```
Could not connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 (172.16.0.3), connection timed out
```

-I tried this (so I think a firewall is not problem):

```
sudo ufw disable
```

What should I do to be able to update OS, and to be able to install Krita (or any other application)?

Comment: It would seem that you are in fact configured to use a proxy.

Comment: All I know basically is that you don't appear to have direct Internet access (if at all).  Do some things work online?  What DNS server are you using?  Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @ivanivan I turned off proxy in browser preferences/advanced/network/settings , but didn't in computer settings/network/network proxy.
So I turned it to "none" but still had the same problem.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes, I have Internet acces, and other answers are in comment under (under Philip answer).

Comment: A proxy wasn't turned off well.

Answer (score 1):

Something is broken with your DNS. `rs.archive.ubuntu.com` should resolve to 147.91.175.253, but in your environment you are getting 172.16.0.3, an address in RFC 1918 space - i.e. an address intended for use within your local network. Looking further down the log, you are getting 172.16.0.3 for *every* DNS lookup.

Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` and see what you're using for a DNS server. If you're not on a corporate network where it might get you into trouble, start using Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 instead. If you are on a corporate network, talk to your IT folk.

Comment: this is what i got:

    cat /etc/resolv.conf# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
    nameserver 127.0.1.1

then I tried 

    ping 8.8.8.8

and waited till: 

    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2180 ttl=60 time=100 ms
    ^C
    --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
    2180 packets transmitted, 2164 received, 0% packet loss, time 2182108ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.981/88.989/1500.079/150.736 ms, pipe 2

[next comment, don't have space here]

Comment: "nameserver 127.0.0.1" means you're using a DNS server on your local machine. Either you set this up, in which case you need to fix your configuration, or your system admin set this up, in which case you need to talk to them.

Comment: And how can I fix it? If I understood the problem is the nameserver and I have to change it? Or can the problem be the fact that I'm on wi-fi internet (while computer is directly connected to router) ?

Comment: That depends *how* you want to fix it. You could fix the configuration of your locally installed nameserver, or you could change your DHCP settings on your network to use a good nameserver. With all due respect, it doesn't sound like you should be running your own nameserver, so I'd reset your network to factory defaults and start again.

Comment: Well I tried "sudo iptables -F" and I'm still getting : "Unable to connect to 172.16.0.3:8080:" Then I tried to connect with cable (not wi-fi) and nothing's change about "sudo apt-get update", but...

Comment: maybe this can say something I'm missing:
after I connected with cable and type this "sudo iptables -F"
timeout error (of sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports) change to:
gpg: requesting key 8AC93F7A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: 172.16.0.3: No route to host
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: No route to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found

Comment: No, stop messing around with iptables or anything like that. **You need to fix your DNS server**. If you don't know what that means or how to do that, **find someone who does**.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because /etc/apt/apt.conf contains:
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://172.16.0.3:8080/";
After deleting its contents, sudo apt-get update should work fine.